# How to turn off lilypond automatic staff width

Tags: lilypond, engraving

So if I engrave music with LilyPond, and I write a few bars, the staves may initially stop in the middle of page (horizontally speaking).

I write some more, and eventually, it reach the edge of the page. It fully fills the page width.

I write some more, and initially, the bars are squeezed to fit in one page width, until there is enough bars to fill exactly two page widths, at which point I have "two lines" of staves.

And then, whatever the number of bars I add, I only have exactly n lines of music. I don't (can't) have five lines and a half, or something.

Is there a way to do it ? To have floating end of the last "line" of staves ? To remove the automatic width of the staves for the last line ? To be precise, what I want is something like :

[image]

Like you'd have with a text paragraph. Each line represent a staff or a group of staves (not the five lines of a staff).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certainly: just put `ragged-last = ##t` into your `paper` block. That should do it.