# How to reduce the width of a staff containing only a rest in LilyPond

Tags: lilypond, engraving

Consider this example :

```
{
#(set-global-staff-size 25)
%\tempo Allegro
\time 4/4
a'4 b' c'' d''
R1
a'4 b' c'' d''
R1
a'4 b' c'' d''
R1
a'4 b' c'' d''
R1
a'4 b' c'' d''
}
```

[image]

Is there a way to impose a smaller width to the bars that only contain a rest, which would give more space to the other bars? (Not best practice but I try to copy a manuscript.)

Knowing that the [Lilypond manual](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/notation/horizontal-spacing-overview.html) states "No workaround exists for decreasing the amount of space."

(Related to [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/98943/how-to-turn-off-lilypond-automatic-staff-width).)

Answer (score 2):

In fact there is. `MultiMeasureRest` use the dummy property `springs-and-rods` to set the actual spacing, so we can actually get rid of all extra spacing by setting

```
\override MultiMeasureRest.springs-and-rods = ##f
```

But more reasonably: `ly:multi-measure-rest::set-spacing-rods` pads the length by the value of the property `bound-padding` to both sides, which defaults to 0.5ss (so the total length is padded by 1ss). Adjust this value as you like

```
\override MultiMeasureRest.bound-padding = #-0.5
```

to achieve wider or narrower spacing. This padding can also be set to a negative value, but can not lead to negative spacing.